# What does "underlying technicality" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "underlying technicality" mean in the following sentence?

> Discuss from the existing scenario/situation up to the proposed
>   system and proceed with its *underlying technicality* but presented in
>   simple and layman's terms. (e.g Hardware, Software, Peopleware,
>   Middleware, Firmware, etc.)

Comment: Please [expand](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/82770/edit) your question to include the research you have embarked upon in trying to define the phrase. What did dictionaries tell about the words? Here are some guidelines on [ask] and some more specific guidelines about [meaning questions](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/).

Answer (score 1):

I would think that *underlying technical aspects* would be more clear and is the meaning that the author was attempting to convey.

Answer (score 0):

Problem or Problems that are inherent or not apparent in but usually happen do to imperfect systems, ideas.

Example, We had it all planned out gas, money, car but we didn't realize that we couldn't bring are family dog with us over the border.  This little underlying technicality cost us big in Time and Money.  While the plan seamed perfect of paper the reality was much different.